# Pass function with parameters, but not its execution result

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my component I have a static `need` property that stores a `function`. Behind the scenes there is middleware that executes this `function` in order to perform some asynchronous API calls before rendering the component. This is how it looks:

```
static need = [
  myFunc(token)
]
```

However this causes issues, as having a `token` parameter there actually executes the function, hence its promise is passed as `need`, instead of `function` itself. For example, this works perfectly fine, as it doesn't execute the function:

```
static need = [
  myFunc
]
```

But this way I have no ability to pass a token. I'm trying to figure out how to pass this function to `need` with a token, but without executing it, as it is done in middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a closure

```
static need = [
    function (token) {
        return myFunc;
    }(token);
]
```

ES6

```
static need = [
    (token => myFunc)(token)
]
```

Comment: Nina, any chance you have an es6 syntax for this? tried `(token) => { return myFunc }(token)` doesn't seem to do the trick

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
var need = [
  myFunc, token
];
```

you can invoke it as

```
need[0].apply(null, need.slice(1-need.length));
```

**Example DEMO**

```js
function a(b){ console.log(b) } 
var  need = [
  a, "1"
];

need[0].apply(null, need.slice(1-need.length));
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have control of `myFunc`:

```
function myFunc(params) {
   return function() {
      // do something with params
   }
}
```

So in order to execute actual function code, you'll have to call it twice: `myFunc('foo')()`, which suits your need to maintain parameters before calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

Probably by now you have resolve the issue but I feel instead of storing it in an array you can create an object & add this as an object property.There is no harm in storing it in an array

```
//Define the function
var need = {
  myFunc:function(token){
   alert(token)
  }
};

// Invoking
need['myFunc'](1);

//dynamic invoke
var dynamicInvoke = 'myFunc';
need[dynamicInvoke](2);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/2xa0fxah/)